# facebook dialog not sending request to friend

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the facebook dialog to send request to my friend using the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                               nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
```

the delegate `- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {` was triggered but apparently I dont see anything on my friends account. I've added him as a tester of the app through the developer account. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/:

> User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not
>   websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas
>   Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

1. Do you have a canvas url specified in your app settings?
2. Also what does the response look like from Facebook at the completion of the dialog? It should look like:

   {
     request: 'REQUEST_OBJECT_ID'
     to:[array of USER_IDs]
   }

Comment: hmm..what is then my canvas url?

Comment: Since you don't know what it is, then you don't have it defined and that's why the requests are not working. Requests won't work properly, per the documentation, without one.

Comment: Can you please confirm that this solution is for iPhone App? Or is it for just Facebook App?

Comment: As quoted above, the Requests are only for Canvas apps.  Canvas apps can be seen on any iPhone.

Comment: So the question is do you also need a canvas page for your **native iOS** app in order to send requests to friends? If not, this answer is totally not answering the original question. Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: At the time I answered the question, that is the way Facebook had it setup.  Facebook is always changing things, so this may no longer be the way Facebook does it.  Check the link to the documents for any changes to the way they do things.

Comment: @DMCS: Was the "sending request to friends from the app" feature introduced only from iOS6 or does the iOS5 supports this feature?

Comment: I don't think iOS6 was public on Feb 7th, 2012.  Wasn't Apple on iOS5 back then?